# Python: Split a String Field into 3 Separate Fields using Lambda

Tags: python, string, pandas, lambda, split

I have a Python data frame which includes a column called "SEGMENT".  I want to break the column up into three columns.  Please see my desired output highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Below is the code I have tried.  Unfortunately I can't even get the first replace statement to work.  The : does not get replaced by -.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
df_stack_ranking['CURRENT_AUM_SEGMENT'] = df_stack_ranking['CURRENT_AUM_SEGMENT'].replace(':', '-')

s = df_stack_ranking['CURRENT_AUM_SEGMENT'].str.split(' ').apply(Series, 1).stack()

s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)

s.name = 'SEGMENT'

df_stack_ranking.join(s.apply(lambda x: Series(x.split(':'))))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SEGMENT': {0: 'Hight:33-48', 1: 'Hight:33-48', 2: 'Very Hight:80-88'}})

df
Out[17]: 
            SEGMENT
0       Hight:33-48
1       Hight:33-48
2  Very Hight:80-88
```

**Solution**

use split to break the column to 3 parts and then expand to create a new DF.

```
df.SEGMENT.str.split(':|-',expand=True)\
  .rename(columns=dict(zip(range(3),\
  ['SEGMENT','SEGMENT RANGE LOW','SEGMENT RANGE HIGH'])))
Out[13]: 
      SEGMENT SEGMENT RANGE LOW SEGMENT RANGE HIGH
0       Hight                33                 48
1       Hight                33                 48
2  Very Hight                80                 88
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `:` or `(|)` `\s*-\s*` (`\s*` means zero or more whitespaces):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SEGMENT': ['Hight: 33 - 48', 'Hight: 33 - 48', 'Very Hight: 80 - 88']})

cols = ['SEGMENT','SEGMENT RANGE LOW','SEGMENT RANGE HIGH']
df[cols] = df['SEGMENT'].str.split(':\s*|\s*-\s*',expand=True)
print (df)
      SEGMENT SEGMENT RANGE LOW SEGMENT RANGE HIGH
0       Hight                33                 48
1       Hight                33                 48
2  Very Hight                80                 88
```

Solution with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
cols = ['SEGMENT','SEGMENT RANGE LOW','SEGMENT RANGE HIGH']
df[cols] = df['SEGMENT'].str.extract('([A-Za-z\s*]+):\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)', expand = True)
print (df)
      SEGMENT SEGMENT RANGE LOW SEGMENT RANGE HIGH
0       Hight                33                 48
1       Hight                33                 48
2  Very Hight                80                 88
```

Comment: Glad can help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because I like naming columns from the `str.extract` regex

```
regex = '\s*(?P<SEGMENT>\S+)\s*:\s*(?P<SEGMENT_RANGE_LOW>\S+)\s*-\s*(?P<SEGMENT_RANGE_HIGH>\S+)\s*'
df.SEGMENT.str.extract(regex, expand=True)

  SEGMENT SEGMENT_RANGE_LOW SEGMENT_RANGE_HIGH
0    High                33                 48
1    High                33                 48
2    High                80                 88
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SEGMENT': ['High: 33 - 48', 'High: 33 - 48', 'Very High: 80 - 88']})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columns = ['SEGMENT', 'SEGMENT RANGE LOW', 'SEGMENT RANGE HIGH']
df['temp'] = df['SEGMENT'].str.replace(': ','-').str.split('-')
for i, c in enumerate(columns):
    df[c] = df['temp'].apply(lambda x: x[i])
del df['temp']
```

Replace colon with a hyphen and then split on hyphen to get list of values for the 3 columns. Then assign values to each of the 3 columns and delete the temporary column.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with the str.extract using regex

```
df.SEGMENT.str.extract('([A-Za-z ]+):(\d+)-(\d+)', expand = True).rename(columns = {0: 'SEGMENT', 1: 'SEGMENT RANGE LOW', 2: 'SEGMENT RANGE HIGH'})

    SEGMENT     SEGMENT RANGE LOW   SEGMENT RANGE HIGH
0   High        33                  48
1   High        33                  48
2   Very High   80                  88
```