# How to do tolist() inplace on one column without removing others ,python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Don't know how to do tolist() on one column without removing other columns.

I have 3 columns

```
category      |        item         |    subcategory

Construction  |  [28, 0, 72168025]  |     tools
```

I want to unpack df.item so ill get:

```
category      |  name   |  price  |   view     |  subcategory

Construction  |   28    |    0    |  72168025  |    tools
```

i did:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.item.tolist(), columns=['Name', 'Price', 'View'])
```

but i get:

```
|  name   |  price  |   view     |

|   28    |    0    |  72168025  |
```

How to include other columns to df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) + [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html)

Join a dataframe constructed from a list of lists:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('item').values.tolist()).add_prefix('item'))
```

#### Example

```
# data from @cronoik
data = [('Construction',[28,0,7216825], 'tools')]
labels = ['category', 'item', 'subcategory']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('item').values.tolist()).add_prefix('item'))

print(df)

       category subcategory  item0  item1    item2
0  Construction       tools     28      0  7216825
```

Answer (score 1):

If your column consists of a list on each row, you don't need `.tolist()` to cast this into separate columns.

Here is one possible approach to resolve this

Generate some dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,1), columns=list('A'))
df['category'] = 'Construction'
df['item'] = [[28,0,72168025]]*df.shape[0]
df['subcategory'] = 'tools'
print(df)
          A      category               item subcategory
0  0.972818  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
1  0.583059  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
2  0.784836  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
3  0.393868  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
4  0.806041  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
5  0.871041  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
6  0.573951  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
7  0.513052  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
8  0.982331  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
9  0.713301  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools
```

Now, use `apply(pd.Series)` on the `item` column ([per this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44298666) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924406/4057186)) to get a separate dataframe, where each list element corresponds to a separate pandas Series, and assign column names

```
df_split = df['item'].apply(pd.Series)
df_split.columns = ['Name', 'Price', 'View']
```

Finally concatenate the original dataframe with the new (split) dataframe

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_split], axis=1)
```

Output

```
print(df)
          A      category               item subcategory  Name  Price      View
0  0.684692  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
1  0.404291  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
2  0.084463  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
3  0.060698  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
4  0.096269  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
5  0.539278  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
6  0.159661  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
7  0.651479  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
8  0.961392  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
9  0.741887  Construction  [28, 0, 72168025]       tools    28      0  72168025
```

(Optional) Drop the original `item` column

```
df.drop(['item'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
          A      category subcategory  Name  Price      View
0  0.833281  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
1  0.229584  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
2  0.403571  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
3  0.822803  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
4  0.968666  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
5  0.053424  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
6  0.759824  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
7  0.766610  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
8  0.752378  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
9  0.056715  Construction       tools    28      0  72168025
```

Edit: although this approach is feasible, there are faster approaches than using `apply` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/4057186).

Answer (score 0):

You could use your original solution and join the result onto your original DataFrame, dropping the original column:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.item.tolist(), columns=['Name', 'Price', 'View'], index=df.index)
final_df = df.join(df2).drop("item", axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this result because you create a new dataframe from your item column. What you actually want to do is to add new columns to your existing dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('Construction',[28,0,7216825], 'tools')]
labels = ['category', 'item', 'subcategory']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)

#Adding the new columns based on the split
df[['name','price', 'view']] = pd.DataFrame(df.item.tolist())
#dropping the unneeded item column
df.drop('item', axis=1, inplace=True )
```